# Tough Sql Server Join Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am building an application  for my semestre exam which will take place in 20 days. My app should assist teachers to build more easily our faculty timetable.

I am working with a database approach (Sql Server 2008 and Delphi XE2). I have a few tables that describe the student formations structure. So I have `Years`, `Series`, `Specializations`, `Groups` and `SemiGroups`. Like in the image `Years` contains `Series`, `Series` contain `Specializations`, `Specializations` contains `Groups` and `Groups` may contain or not `SemiGroups`. I have also tables with `Courses`, `Teachers`, `ClassRooms`, `Days` and `HourlyIntervals`.

There are a few conditions:

1. A teacher may take a course with one or more Specializations, OR with one or more Groups, OR with one or more Semigroups.
2. The second condition is that Courses are of 3 types: TeachingCourse, Seminary, Laboratory (only two from three possible for each CourseName).(stored in the column Scheduler.CourseType char(3) )
3. The third one: Courses can be kept in all weeks of a semester, or in oddweek numbers,or in weeks number dividable by 2.(stored in the column Scheduler.Week char(3))

So I am storing the correlations in a SchedulerTable.

[image]

So if a Group has a course with a certain teacher I will introduce only the corresponding IDs.

I built almost all the data introducing forms and now I am at the Reporting part of the application. I am using Report Services from MSSQL 2008. 
I want to list a scheduler that will include all the correlations for a certain Specialization (that one includes  Groups and/or Semigroups). I have managed to show all correlations for Groups belonging to that certain Specializations but I can't manage to show alse the Specialization and Semigroups courses.

This is the query that returns me Groups correlations from a certain Specialization.

```
SELECT    Days.DayName, HourlyIntervals.HourlyIntervalName, Scheduler.Week, Scheduler.CourseType,  Courses.CourseName, ClassRooms.ClassRoomName, Teachers.TeacherName,Specializations.SpecName, Groups.GroupsName
 FROM   Scheduler INNER JOIN
        Groups ON Scheduler.GroupID = Groups.GroupID INNER JOIN
        Days ON Scheduler.DayID = Days.DayID INNER JOIN
        HourlyIntervals ON Scheduler.HourlyIntervalID = HourlyIntervals.HourlyIntervalID INNER JOIN
        Teachers ON Scheduler.TeacherID = Teachers.TeacherID INNER JOIN
        Courses ON Scheduler.CourseID = Courses.CourseID INNER JOIN
        ClassRooms ON Scheduler.ClassRoomID = ClassRooms.ClassRoomID INNER JOIN
        Specializations ON Groups.IDSpec = Specializations.IDSpec

 WHERE  (Specializations.ID = @SpecID)

 ORDER BY Days.DayID, HourlyIntervals.HourlyIntervalID
```

But I want it to return  corelations for SemiGroups,Groups and Specialization for that certain Specialization. I tried to add a join with this one Scheduler.SemiGroupID=Semigroups.SemigroupID but the query returns 0 results then.  I don't know if it can be done what I want but I will be thankful to anyone that points me an idea. Or should I use another structure for my correlations table (`SchedulerTable`).

[This is a sample report](http://feaa.ucv.ro/cm/images/stories/docs/Licenta2012/Orar%20anul%20I%2C%20Sem%20II%2C%202011-2012-bun.pdf) (a PDF file) which I would like to get:

Edit Reason: Better explaining of the issue

Comment: I removed the Delphi XE2 tag because this question has absolutely nothing to do with Delphi; it's strictly a SQL Server question.

Comment: Not sure I'm getting you semi-groups per specialisation seems an easy step given you've done groups per specialisation. Can you put the query you have done in the question?

Comment: @Tony: I want to thank you for your interest in my question; i edited it and put the code for my query.

Answer (score 0):

So why isn't this the solution?

```
SELECT    Days.DayName, HourlyIntervals.HourlyIntervalName, Scheduler.Week, Scheduler.CourseType,  Courses.CourseName, ClassRooms.ClassRoomName, Teachers.TeacherName,Specializations.SpecName, SemiGroups.GroupsName
 FROM   Scheduler 
  INNER JOIN SemiGroups On Scheduler.SemiGroupId = SemiGroups.SemiGroupId        
  INNER JOIN Groups ON SemiGroups.GroupID = SemiGroups.Groups
  INNER JOIN Days ON Scheduler.DayID = Days.DayID 
  INNER JOIN HourlyIntervals ON Scheduler.HourlyIntervalID = HourlyIntervals.HourlyIntervalID 
  INNER JOIN Teachers ON Scheduler.TeacherID = Teachers.TeacherID 
  INNER JOIN Courses ON Scheduler.CourseID = Courses.CourseID 
  INNER JOIN ClassRooms ON Scheduler.ClassRoomID = ClassRooms.ClassRoomID 
  INNER JOIN Specializations ON Groups.IDSpec = Specializations.IDSpec

 WHERE  (Specializations.ID = @SpecID)
 ORDER BY Days.DayID, HourlyIntervals.HourlyIntervalID
```

Though I'll admit to a furrowed brow about whether GroupID in Schedules was the GroupID of the SemiGroupID in that row. Looks likes that bit isn't normalised.

Comment: @Tony-I have a done a test Scheduler Table that has 25 records. 5 records with SpecID, 15 records with GroupID and another 5 with SemiGroupID. All these 25 records belong to a certain Specialization. When I run the query it only returns records belonging to GroupID. About normalization i don`t know where i am wrong because a Specialization belongs to a Serie, a Group belongs to a Specialization, a SemiGroup belongs to a Group.Please, could you give me more specific sugestions ?

Comment: @CristianVasuica, can you have group with no semi groups? The problem seems to be. In Schedules you could have a group and semigroup where the group in semigroups was a different group.

Comment: Yes I could have a group without semigroups. I am not sure that i understand what you mean. I will show you the way i am entering records in Schedules Table: Lets suppose I have a specialization named SpecInformatics and this special has two groups. Each group contains 2 Semigroups. When I want to set for Semigroup1 of Group1 of Informatics I am introducing only SemiGroup1ID in the table. I am not introducing Group1ID or SpecInformaticsID. I am doing it wrong? Should I enter SpecInformaticsID and Group1ID as well?

Comment: Wrong would be a matter of opinion I was simple misled by the column names.

Comment: I can't figure out whether I'm missing something here. Seems to me you need to union three queries, one for specialism, one for groups and one for semigroups.

Comment: I have tried the union but it is mixing arround the results and they are not correct that way. Maybe I am doing it wrong.However I will extract for the moment the correlation individually for Specialization, Groups and Semigroups. When I will "get wiser" I hope that I will fix this. thank you again for your support!